# Including External Assets to the APK

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, apk, flashdevelop

I am using FlashDevelop 4.0.1 RTM to create a simple Android app and I would like to ask how to include external assets (images, xml & sounds located inside the bin folder) to the apk package.

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry I posted an answer assuming you were using Eclipse/Flash Builder as I've seen questions where the issue was the file exclusions setup in the IDE, normally though I believe all assets are copied from the specified source folder into the bin folder and subsequently into the apk.  The file exclusions may still be relevant but I'm not familiar with FlashDevelop to say.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see, **you don't need the external assets to be actually external, they can be embedded**, since anyway you want them embedded into the apk.

So just embed them into your swf. Instead of loading assets from the bin folder, do this:

```
public class YourClass {
    // Embed the asset
    [Embed(source='assets/yourImage.jpg')] private var yourImageClass:Class;

    // ...

    // Use the asset
    private function someFunction():void {
        var yourImage:DisplayObject = DisplayObject(new yourImageClass());
    }
}
```

You can embed pretty much any kind of file.

Comment: From your question I cannot infer whether you really have some reason to have the assets external rather than embedded.