# Detecting Unused Functions in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, stored-functions

I have recently finished developing a MySQL Database. During development I created multiple stored functions that I actually used within various views. While experimenting, the number of of version functions kept increasing and now I want to remove the ones that are not actually used inside views.

Is there a quick way to list all these functions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [List of Stored Procedures/Functions Mysql Command Line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/733349/list-of-stored-procedures-functions-mysql-command-line)

Comment: I don't want to list all the stored functions, just the ones that are not used inside views.

Comment: You will need to go through each view and find functions or write a script to do so.

Comment: Delete them all and look for errors.

Comment: @njk: Please answer some of his questions so that he has answers to choose from to accept.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit No need. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10358302/executing-queries-in-mongodb-with-greek-characters-using-javascript-returns-no-r/679449) seems to have a good answer; [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11240197/angularjs-and-rest-service) and [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9898117/including-external-assets-to-the-apk) have no responses from the OP.

Comment: @njk: Well at least you have now checked :)